# Remove args if request_uri begins with specific strings/regex (with some exceptions) - Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to redirect (301) several locations if they have query params at same locations without query params, but with some exceptions.

For example, I want these locations behaviour:

- /bob/marley -> not redirect
- /bob/marley?query=string -> redirect to /bob/marley
- /bob/marley/cat?name=dude -> redirect to /bob/marley/cat
- /bob/marley/dog?name=jim -> redirect to /bob/marley/dog
- /bob/marley/search?query=string -> not redirect

How can I do this if it would be dozens of these rules. Maybe organize it at separate file with map directive or something? Can anyone explain, please?

Comment: Shouldn't be better to handle such tasks in application level? I suppose it's application/controller level, not web server task to handle such deep logic (as for web server). Especially, if you planning to extend your app with more functionality. IMHO.

Comment: I would not like to make a load in the application, if it can be taken out in nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the answer for the example above would be the following:

```
http section:

map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
  "~^(?P<path>\/bob\/marley\/?(?:(?!\?|search).)*)(\?.*)$"  $path;
}

server section:

if ($request_uri_path) {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host$request_uri_path;
}
```